# Reference between object but not in primitive. Why???

Tags: java, oop

In java we can refer one object with in more reference variables. But we can not use that in to primitive data types with out using static but it is much more different.

Here,

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50); 
           System.out.println(r1);

           Rectangle r2 = r1;

           r2.grow(10, 20);
           System.out.println(r1);
           System.out.println(r2);
```

same thing in primitive,

```
double n1 = 150;
            double n2 = n1;

            n2 = n2 * 20; 

            System.out.println(n1);
            System.out.println(n2);
```

but acting differently. I know that is different but I need to know that Why?? Whats going on in the memory??

Comment: Though I'm trying really hard, I can't understand what have you written.

Comment: Your memory is being erased. Oh wait what?

Comment: I think he's saying that when you change r2, r1 changes, but when you change n2, n1 stays the same... but he should have written the output. That's true.

Comment: The question is clear. I do not get the down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables directly contain *values*. In the case of a primitive, the value *is* the primitive. In the case of an object reference, the value is the *reference*, not the object.

In pictures:

```
int a = 5;
```

gives us

```
+-----+
|  a  |
+-----+
|  5  |
+-----+
```

but

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

gives us

```
+-----+
|  f  |
+-----+               +--------------+
| ref |-------------->| A Foo object |
+-----+               +--------------+
```

Since the value held by `f` is a *reference*, it *refers* to something elsewhere in memory.

Whenever you assign one variable to another (or pass a variable's value into a function), you *copy* the value held by that variable. So if we have `a` and `f` as above and do this:

```
int b = a;
```

now we have

```
+-----+
|  a  |
+-----+
|  5  |
+-----+

+-----+
|  b  |
+-----+
|  5  |
+-----+
```

The *value* in `a` was copied to `b`.

Now suppose we do this:

```
Foo f2 = f;
```

Remember that what `f` holds is a *reference*, not the object. So we get this:

```
+-----+
|  f  |
+-----+
| ref |-------+
+-----+       |
              |       +--------------+
+-----+       +-------| A Foo object |
|  f2 |       |       +--------------+
+-----+       |
| ref |-------+
+-----+
```

The *value* in `f` was copied to `f2`, but that value is a reference, and so both `f` and `f2` *refer* to the same object elsewhere in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The case is that for primitive you always assign the value and for object the reference to value.

```
int a = 10; //Assign to variable a value of 10
int b = a;  //Assigne to variable b value that is under adress of a

Object A = new Object(); // Create instance of class Object and assigne the reference to variable A;
Object B = A; // Assign the reference to  B of object under adress A;
```

To read more about the concept follow [this link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)

Answer (score 1):

(1)Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50);

- create the object of rectangle class

(2)Rectangle r2 = r1;

- hold the object reference in r2

(3)r2.grow(10, 20);

it change the variable then, this change also show in r1